# Loading CachedImageView in Swift4 I get error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x1b2baacc0)

Tags: swift

Any help would me much appreciated...

Using the following 'getLoggedinUserDetails()' function that accepts the current user's '**uid**' as a parameter and **returns** via a handler a 'CurrentUser' **object** with the a '**name**' and '**profilePictureURL**' String attributes fetched from Firebase.

```
func 'getLoggedinUserDetails(uid: String, currentUserHandler: @escaping (_ currentUser: CurrentUser) -> ())
```

I get a 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS' error when loading the image with the passed-in URL string using '.loadImage' from the installed LBTAComponents libraries in my project.

The '**profileImg**' is of type '**CachedImageView**!'

thanks in advance.

```
import LBTAComponents

@IBOutlet weak var profileImg: CachedImageView!


//Displays the logged in user details eg; profile image and name
func displayUserDetails(){

    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {

        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        DataService.run.getLoggedinUserDetails(forUID: uid, currentUserHandler: { (user) in

            self.nameLbl.text = user.name
            self.profileImg.loadImage(urlString: user.profilePictureURL) //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x1b2baacc0)

        })
    }

}//end func
```